Permission Denied error when creating new files using Laravel Sail commands or VS Code for an app running on Docker and Laravel-Sail?
I am a Ubuntu user and I recently started warming up to Docker.
I have done the Docker installation on Ubuntu 24.04, I have managed to add Laravel Sail and I have managed to run the application successfully.
However, I am facing ownership restrictions when I try to create files using ./vendor/bin/sail artisan make:model since the app folder/files are under the logged in user while those on the docker container are owned by the root user.
I tried changing the project folder & file ownership by logging into the shell and using chwown -R sail:sail. I was able to create the modules but then I got restricted when saving any edits done using my editor (VS Code). I have also tried chown -R www-data:www-data, changed folder permissions, added these two variables:
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000

in my .env but I still get the restrictions.
How do I resolve this conflict so that I can run my application on docker using Laravel Sail, create modules using sail commands and use VS Code to edit my files?

I encountered the same issue today when trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. I realized that there was already a user "ubuntu" with the ID 1000, which generated an error when adding usermod -u $WWWUSER sail.
ubuntu id 1000
To resolve this, in the supervisord.conf file, I modified the line user with user=ubuntu to have the same 1000 UID.
maybe using a variable would be better, you can find the contents of supervisord.conf and other files here supervisord.conf
Hope this helps

Thank you this has worked for me as well.

you can remove the ubuntu user, create the container as usual, connect to the terminal with sail root-shell, after that php artisan sail:publish
go to the docker folder on the project's root, and change the docker file, adding this line right after FROM ubuntu:22.04:
RUN userdel ubuntu && groupdel ubuntu || true
